# Learning Hyperledger Fabric & setting up a simple network. Stuck on an error while trying to regenerate the channel configuration transaction

Tags: configuration, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

Command I am using on Terminal:
"configtxgen -profile OneOrgOrdererGenesis -outputCreateChannelTx /Users/anmolmanchanda/go/src/github.com/18738798/fabric-samples/fabric-network/channel.tx -channelID channel"

Configtx.yaml:

```
Organizations:
  - &OrdererOrg
    Name: OrdererOrg
    ID: OrdererMSP
    MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/msp
    Policies:
      Readers:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
      Writers:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
      Admins:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.admin')"
    OrdererEndpoints:
      - orderer.example.com:7050
  - &Org1          # Anchor definition for Org1
      Name: Org1
      ID: Org1MSP
      MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp
      AdminPrincipal: Role.MEMBER
      Policies:
        Readers:
          Type: Signature
          Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin', 'Org1MSP.peer', 'Org1MSP.client')"
        Writers:
          Type: Signature
          Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin', 'Org1MSP.client')"
        Admins:
          Type: Signature
          Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin')"
  - &Org2
      Name: Org2
      ID: Org2MSP
      MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/msp
      Policies:
        Readers:
          Type: Signature
          Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.admin', 'Org2MSP.peer', 'Org2MSP.client')"
        Writers:
          Type: Signature
          Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.admin', 'Org2MSP.client')"
        Admins:
          Type: Signature
          Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.admin')"
        Endorsement:
          Type: Signature
          Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.peer')"

Capabilities:
  Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
    V2_0: true
  Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
    V2_0: true
  Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
    V2_5: true

Application: &ApplicationDefaults
  Organizations:
  Policies:
    Readers:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Readers"
    Writers:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Writers"
    Admins:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
    LifecycleEndorsement:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"
    Endorsement:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"
  Capabilities:
    <<: *ApplicationCapabilities

Orderer: &OrdererDefaults
  Addresses:
    - orderer.example.com:7050
  BatchTimeout: 2s
  BatchSize:
    MaxMessageCount: 10
    AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB
    PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB
  Organizations:
  Policies:
    Readers:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Readers"
    Writers:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Writers"
    Admins:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
    BlockValidation:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Writers"

Channel: &ChannelDefaults
  Policies:
    Readers:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Readers"
    Writers:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Writers"
    Admins:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
  Capabilities:
    <<: *ChannelCapabilities

Profiles:
  OneOrgOrdererGenesis:
    <<: *ChannelDefaults
    Orderer:
      <<: *OrdererDefaults
      Organizations:
        - *OrdererOrg
      Capabilities: *OrdererCapabilities
    Consortiums:
      SampleConsortium:
        Organizations:
          - *Org1
          - *Org2
    Application:
      <<: *ApplicationDefaults
      Organizations:
        - *Org1
        - *Org2
      Capabilities: *ApplicationCapabilities
```

I have tried updating the yaml file and checking if all the indentation is correct. I am getting this error:
Error on outputChannelCreateTx: config update generation failure: cannot define a new channel with no Consortium value